# How to programmatically dismiss FB Dialog on iphone..?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, fbdialogs

I have a situation where I have to use FBDialog.. now what happens at times that the internet might get disconnected while the Dialog is fetching friend list from server and this dialog window stays on top forever.. How can I close this window programmatically..?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: there is a colution for that.

Comment: Call this method   -(void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled    wherever u want to close the FB Dailogue box. i mean call the method in connection Error method.

Comment: Did you read [FBDialog.h](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/src/FBDialog.h)? There are a handful of dismiss methods there...

Comment: well this is how I call the dialog - "[appDelegate.facebook dialog:@"apprequests" andParams:params  andDelegate:self];".. How do I get the Dialog instance in one of my properties to dismiss it..?